# Счётик в массиве показывает не верное значение

Tags: php, sql, массивы

Приветствую, следующий код:

```
$usertr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allurlszhhk");
$rowtr = mysql_fetch_array($usertr); 
$count = count($rowtr);
echo $count ;
```

на экран выводит 6, когда полей в БД 275

Comment: Щип?...........

Comment: )) Не сплю! Есть идеи?)

Comment: У Вас 275 столбцов или строк?

Comment: Строк http://shot.qip.ru/00tXa3-13YtCRM9J/

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` возвращает очередную запись, а не все сразу, разве нет? И шесть там полей, выходит.

Comment: **Внимание** Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалено в PHP 7.0.0. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` возвращает одну строку данных. Для подсчёта количества записей в таблице можно использовать:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$total = $row[0];
echo $total;
```

Comment: May be... `mysql_num_rows`?

Comment: Всё верно спасибо!

Comment: @Other таким образом мы только получим количество, а если через `mysql_num_rows` то мы все данные выберем а потом их посчитаем. А если в таблице не 275 строк, а несколько миллионов?

Comment: Просто предложил. Я с `mysql_*` не работал, только с `PDO`.

Comment: @Other да и в PDO `rowCount` сначала выполняет запрос, а потом считает строки

Comment: Вроде похоже на то. Странный этот `PHP` :)